# Can't Get This Redirect To Work In .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'v been struggling with this .htaccess file for a few hours ..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
                RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example.html$ http://www.example.com? [R=301,L]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (google|yahoo|slurp|bing|msnbot|yandex) [OR]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (zzzzzz)
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [OR]
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (htm|php|phps|shtml|xml|xhtml|phtml|asp|aspx)$ [NC]
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !sitemap_xml_xml.php
                RewriteCond //sitemap_xml_xml.php -f
                RewriteRule ^.*$    /sitemap_xml_xml.php [L]
                </IfModule>
```

I want to delete everything in the .htaccess except for my rewrite rule. At the moment my rewrite rule wont work and I don't know what the other rules are. Our developer left and I really want to get this done. Would appreciate the help. I don't think I need anything except for the 301 redirect.

Comment: Which rule you want to make it work?

Comment: Need someone to edit it, delete everything but only leave the 301 redirect rule and make it work. I tried but it does not work when I delete it all and only leave the 301 redirect

Comment: So you want `http://example.com/example.html` to goto `http://example.com`?

Comment: Yeh that is correct. Its a very simple ask. I want to be able to delete all the rules except the redirect rule. I have tried myself but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ok place this rule as your very first line:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/example\.html$ http://www.example.com
```

Comment: What would the full .htaccess file look like? Do I need rewrite mod on and do I need the <IfModule> at the top? Sorry but I am a complete newbie

Comment: You just need this one line in your .htaccess nothing else.